# Unexpected ',' expecting ')' in update_attributes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I'm trying to make a Migration but I'm having some troubles. When I try to run "rake db:migrate" on Heroku I got an error message. Now I discover in my localhost that my code in the migration has something wrong - but I don't know what's.

This is the code of my migration:

```
def change
    add_column :comments, :likes_count, :integer, :default => 0
    Comment.all().each do |comment|
        comment.update_attribute(:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
        comment.save        
    end
  end
```

And this is the error that I get on my console (when I try to copy and paste this code on "rails console"):

```
 SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
c.update_attribute (:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
                                 ^
(irb):3: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

Someone can help me?

--------------------- Edit ---------------------------
The strange is: I already run this migration on localhost, and everything in localhost works. But when I try to run a "rake db:migrate" on Heroku, I got an error - and when I try to run the same code on the rails console, I got an error too (as you can see above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you need to reset the column information so that the table knows about its new column before you add values to it.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class

You also don't need the () in `Comment.all().each`, `Comment.all.each` is fine. Nor do you need the explicit save, update_attribute will save the change for you (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attribute)

Finally, your error message doesn't match your code, there is a rogue space in the method call:

```
c.update_attribute (:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
```

remove that space

```
c.update_attribute(:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
```

and see what happens.

Edit: Migration after fixes

```
def change
  add_column :comments, :likes_count, :integer, :default => 0

  Comment.reset_column_information

  Comment.all.each do |comment|
    comment.update_attribute(:likes_count, comment.likes.count)      
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need `Comment.all.each`, `Comment.each` is even finer.

Comment: @Spajus, are you sure about that? `Comment` is a class, not a scope.

Comment: I'm still having troubles: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `comment' for main:Object
 from (irb):6:in `block in irb_binding'
 from (irb):5:in `each'

Comment: @Matt, you're right, I meant `Comment.find_each`, which would do batches and go easier on your DB. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each

Comment: @FernandoPaladini are you sure your database is connecting properly and the comments table exists? Is your Comment model valid? Try opening a console on the server and typing `Comment.last.likes.count` - let us know what happens.

Comment: I verified my code on Heroku and I find this line on my "comments.rb" and "post.rb": attr_readonly :likes_count. I removed this line and migrate the DB, and surprise: everything works! Thanks for everyone. I will mark this answer as a correct because I think it is the best answer and can help more people in future.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that you have a space between the opening bracket and the method name.

Instead of:

```
comment.update_attribute (:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
```

try:

```
comment.update_attribute(:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
```

Also the error message mentions `c.update_attribute (:likes_count, comment.likes.count)`. Notice the `c` instead of `comment`.

So, instead of:

```
Comment.all().each do |c|
  c.update_attribute(:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
  c.save
end
```

do:

```
Comment.all.each do |comment|
  comment.update_attribute(:likes_count, comment.likes.count)
end
```

Note that it is not necessary to do `comment.save`. `comment.update_attribute` will already execute the query.

Comment: I got: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `comment' for main:Object
 from (irb):6:in `block in irb_binding'
 from (irb):5:in `each'

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: I updated my answer. Next time, please post your *actual* code. Not what you think your code is.

Comment: But I post my actual code dude, I don't change anything, but I'm still having troubles... (the problem above)

Comment: @FernandoPaladini, if that is your actual code, why does the error message say `c.update_attribute` instead of `comment.update_attribute`? Are you using `c` somewhere else?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: No, that's *not* your actual code. The error message you posted does not belong to the code you posted. The error message contains an excerpt of the code where the error occurred and that excerpt does not exist anywhere in the code you posted. Either you posted the wrong code or the wrong error. Until you post the *actual* code and the *actual* error, there is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I verified my code on Heroku and I find this line on my "comments.rb" and "post.rb": attr_readonly :likes_count. I removed this line and migrate the DB, and surprise: everything works! Thanks for everyone. I will mark this answer as a correct because I think it is the best answer and can help more people in future.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
def change
  add_column :comments, :likes_count, :integer, :default => 0
  Comment.all.each do |comment|
    comment.update_attribute('likes_count', comment.likes.count)
  end
end
```

Comment: Got: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `comment' for main:Object
 from (irb):10:in `block in irb_binding'
 from (irb):9:in `each'